# Writing raw binary to a file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, file-io, huffman-code

I'm trying to do some Huffman coding in Haskell, but am having a hard time figuring out how to save the resulting 1s and 0s as they are instead of as a string. So far, I've read the following--

https://wiki.haskell.org/Dealing_with_binary_data

https://wiki.haskell.org/Binary_IO

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Binary.html

--but am still pretty confused as to how to deal with my specific situation. Similarly, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to write the tree structure

```
data HTree = Leaf Char Int
           | Branch HTree HTree Int
             deriving (Show)
```

used to decode the data to a file. (HTree is the structure I'm using to store the Huffman Tree).

Comment: Take a look at [Data.ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring)

Comment: See: https://wiki.haskell.org/Dealing_with_binary_data

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to take a look at the `Put` monad in `Data.Binary.Put`. You didn't provide any code example but something to get you started:

```
-- just an example with some made up encoding  

huffmanEncode :: HTree -> Put
huffmanEncode (Leaf c val) = do
    putWord16be 0xf00
    putCharUtf8 c
    putWord32be $ fromIntegral val
huffmanEncode (Branch l r x) = do
    putWord16be 0xbaf
    putWord32be $ fromIntegral x
    huffmanEncode l
    huffmanEncode r
```

You would then "run" your encoder thus: `runPut $ huffmanEncode myTree`

Comment: _obviously_ this is some made up encoding.. I have no clue how you want to encode this ;-)